# Как залогиниться на сайт?

Tags: java, парсер, post, авторизация, jsoup

Необходимо зайти на сайт oddsportal.com, чтобы в дальнейшем парсить его с помощью jsoup. 
Логин и пароль настоящие.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Connection.Response loginForm = null;
    Document document = null;

    String username = "rezubaj";
    String password = "qwerty";

    try {
        loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.oddsportal.com/login")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0")
                .data("login-username", username)
                .data("login-password", password)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        document  = Jsoup.connect("https://www.oddsportal.com/").cookies(loginForm.cookies()).get(); 
    } catch (IOException ie) {
         ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    Elements el = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("href", "/profile/rezubaj/");
    System.out.println(el.text());
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А проблемы то с чем возникли?

Comment: @Suvitruf, я не совсем понимаю как это работает, но думаю, что этот код должен возвращать html страничку после входа. Чтобы это проверить я решил вывести свой ник, но ничего не происходит. `Elements el = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("href", "/profile/rezubaj/");
    System.out.println(el.text());`

Comment: @ИгорьМасленников может потому что сайт написан на Javacript?